# Handling localization with Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am currently integrating an endpoint that returns a list of notifications.Problem is, every field of the notification may be in different language :

```
{
    "title": {
        "fr": "...",
        "en": "..."
    },
    "subtitle": {
        "fr": " ...",
        "en": "..."
    },
    "contents": {
        "fr": "...",
        "en": "..."
    }
}
```

How can I define a POJO that is capable to hold this data, without listing every language in every field ?

My goal is to retrieve the notification contents according to the current user Locale, and if the language is not available, fall back to english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using GSON for parsing, try defining title, subtitle and content as `Map<String, String>` where key is the locale and value is localized text. Then create a helper class/methods for accessing the data and do the fallback there if map doesn't contain the key.

Answer (score 0):

As Niko suggested, using a `Map<String, String>` does the job

**Notification POJO**

```
public class Notification {
    @SerializedName("title")
    public Map<String, String> title;

    @SerializedName("subtitle")
    public Map<String, String> subtitle;

    @SerializedName("contents")
    public Map<String, String> contents;
}
```

**NotificationHelper**

```
public class NotificationHelper {
    private static final String DEFAULT_LOCAL_KEY = Locale.ENGLISH.getLanguage().toLowerCase();

    @Nullable
    public static String getTitle(@NonNull Notification notification) {
        Map<String, String> title = getNotificationField(notification, "title");

        if (title == null) return null;

        return getLocalizedValue(title);
    }

    @Nullable
    public static String getSubtitle(@NonNull Notification notification) {
        Map<String, String> subtitle = getNotificationField(notification, "subtitle");

        if (subtitle == null) return null;

        return getLocalizedValue(subtitle);
    }

    @Nullable
    public static String getContents(@NonNull Notification notification) {
        Map<String, String> contents = getNotificationField(notification, "contents");

        if (contents == null) return null;

        return getLocalizedValue(contents);
    }

    @Nullable
    private static Map<String, String> getNotificationField(Notification notification, @NonNull String field) {
        switch (field) {
            case "title":
                return notification.title;
            case "subtitle":
                return notification.subtitle;
            case "contents":
                return notification.contents;
            default:
                 return null;
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    private static String getLocalizedValue(@NonNull Map<String, String> field) {
        String localized = field.get(Locale.getLanguage().getCountry().toLowerCase());

        if (localized == null) {
            // Try to retrieve the english value instead
            return field.get(DEFAULT_LOCAL_KEY);
        }

         return localized;
    }
}
```